# file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents

I am currently having issues with my going into an infinite loading state and hitting a 505 Gateway when using file_get_contents for reading the response of an API and parsing the JSON.

```
Here is the code: 
<?php 

try {

  while(true) { 
    $url = 'http://floodcrm.net/api.php?key=MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE&method=get_invite';

   $jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
   $json = json_decode($jsonData,true);

   echo $json['code'];

   if(@file_get_contents($url))
   {
   break;
   }
   sleep(2);
  }




}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

It can work fine, but after a while the site will just die again.
Really hope I can have some help with this.

Comment: It looks like a problem with the specific API you are interacting with. You will have to check their documentation to figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: There really isn’t much to their documentation, but what I will state is that. The API works perfectly, if I visit it through it’s normal API.php I get the response I need instantly. It’s just having a hard time communication over my platform.